# Return key if variable in associated values array?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a technical dictionary that I am using to correct various spellings of technical terms.

How can I use this structure (or restructure the below code to work) in order to return the `key` for any alternate spelling?

For example, if someone has written `"craniem"` I wish to return `"cranium"`. I've tried a number of different constructions, including the one below, and cannot quite get it to work.

```
def techDict():
    myDict = {
        'cranium' : ['cranum','crenium','creniam','craniem'],
        'coccyx'  : ['coscyx','cossyx','koccyx','kosicks'],
        '1814A'   : ['Aero1814','A1814','1814'],
        'SodaAsh' : ['sodaash','na2co3', 'soda', 'washingsoda','sodacrystals']
    }
    return myDict

techDict = techDict()
correctedSpelling = next(val for key, val in techDict.iteritems() if val=='1814')
print(correctedSpelling)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reverse and flatten your dictionary:

```
tech_dict = {
    'cranium': ['cranum', 'crenium', 'creniam', 'craniem'],
    'coccyx': ['coscyx', 'cossyx', 'koccyx', 'kosicks'],
    '1814A': ['Aero1814', 'A1814', '1814'],
    'SodaAsh': ['sodaash', 'na2co3', 'soda', 'washingsoda', 'sodacrystals'],
}

lookup = {val: key for key, vals in tech_dict.items() for val in vals}
                                            # ^ note dict.iteritems doesn't exist in 3.x
```

Then you can trivially get:

```
corrected_spelling = lookup['1814']
```

This is far more efficient than potentially scanning through every list for every key in the dictionary to find your search term.

Also note: 1. compliance with [the official style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/); and 2. that I've removed the `techDict` function entirely - it was pointless to write a function just to create a dictionary, especially as you immediately shadowed the function with the dictionary it returned so you couldn't even call it again.

Answer (score 3):

Using **in** instead of **=** will do the trick

```
next(k for k, v in techDict.items() if 'craniem' in v)
```

Comment: Iterating over a dict and looking up strings in lists is abuse of data structures (read: it's slow and arguably ugly code). A much better solution is to invert the dict like jonrsharpe did in his answer, which makes looking up the correct spelling trivial and O(1).